# Do the ICAO and IATA codes for an airport ever change?

Tags: airport, icao, iata

Do ICAO and IATA codes ever change for airports in time? If they do, how often does it occur? I am developing an app for airports and I am thinking of setting the uniqueness of an airport through ICAO or IATA codes.

Comment: The app you're developing, I'm assuming that you'll probably be using some sort of a database to get the ICAO codes. That said, the database admin will probably handle the updates.

Comment: This might be straying into software development, but whereas those codes might make good *unique indexes* they might not make good *primary keys*. You mention the former, but I worry you actually mean the latter

Comment: We're just a few months away from IST changing from LTBA to LTFM https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Istanbul_New_Airport

Answer (score 6):

Yes it does happen.

1. A city can build a new airport, in which case it will usually get a new ICAO code, but will get the original IATA (city) code. For example, Oslo changed from Fornebu to Gardemoen - Fornebu is ENFB, Gardemoen is ENGM; the OSL code was Fornebu but uis now Gardemoen.
2. A city can rename its airport for political reasons, so again the codes are liable to change.
   Example 1 is New York - Idlewild KIDL was change to John F Kennedy KJFK
   Example 2 is Johannesburg - Jan Smuts International was FAJS, then renamed to Oliver Tambo International FAOR.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  It's a pretty big deal so it won't happen often.

Changing the major airport for a city is a big reason.  I think both Denver and Austin did this (new airport opened with a different code, then took over the old airport code).

Renames can also happen.  JFK used to be IDL.

Comment: Another example would be Hong Kong...

Comment: And Beijing, Bangkok, Istanbul…